# bootstrap3, jquery try to make vertical align

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to make vertical align for bootstrap col-md* columns. I have two blocks with a text and with an image. I need that the blocks will be equal on height and the block with some text will have center vertical align. My solution below, but it isn't work correctly. Please, help me)

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="some-text">Some text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="some-img"><img src="..." width="100%"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.some-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.some-text').each(function() {
  var newH = 0;
  $(this).parent().siblings().each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() > newH)
    {
      newH = $(this).height();
    }
  });
  $(this).parent().css('height', newH);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with **Flexbox**

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/449/)

```css
@media(min-width: 992px) {
  .content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .box img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row content">
  <div class="col-md-6 box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque omnis quaerat assumenda. Sed nam molestiae eligendi. Ratione labore doloremque exercitationem id, reprehenderit ipsum! Totam et veritatis sapiente! Iusto, molestias debitis!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 box">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/450x250">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"You should do this with Flexbox instead of JQuery"* ...depending on your browser support requirements...I think you meant.